# Notify of new files with inotify

Tags: php, shell, inotify

I need to make a script that notifies a log file when a new file enters a directory. I would like to use inotify as a shell script or PHP, most examples I have found are in C. Can someone give me an example of this?

In addition, can inotify know when a file is done being copied?

Comment: See: [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), and [`inotify`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) for the possible events triggered (the closing of a file / file is done being copied is also capturable).

Answer (score 4):

This shell command will write to `logfile` whenever a file is created in `/path/to/dir`:

```
inotifywait -m -e create /path/to/dir >>logfile
```

Explanation:

- `-m` tells inotifywait to keep running.  The default is to exit after the first event
- `-e create` tells inotifywait to only report on file *create* events.  (Depending on what you want to accomplish, you might be more interested in *close* events.)
- `/path/to/dir` is the target directory to watch.  Subdirectories are not monitored unless the recursive option, `-r` is specified.
- `>>logfile`  tells the shell to redirect all output to the file `logfile`.  If you leave this part off, output will be directed to stdout and you can watch in real time as files are created.

#### Monitoring more events

`inotifywait` will report on several different events.  As an example, I ran `inotifywait` in one window while writing to a file from another window:

```
$ inotifywait -m .
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
./ OPEN myfile
./ MODIFY myfile
./ MODIFY myfile
./ MODIFY myfile
./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE myfile
```

Because the above has no redirection, all output appears on the terminal.

The OPEN event signifies the files initial creation.  The CLOSE events indicates that the process is done.

The exact set of events that `inotifywait` will show you depends on what system calls the program that you are monitoring uses.  Do a test like the above to find out.